# Как в строчке заменить последовательность элементов на количество вхождений?

Tags: python, строки

Допустим у меня есть строка `"aaabbbcc"` и мне нужно заменить все  `"a"` на `"a3"`,  где `3` это количество вхождений и так далее с другими буквами.

Comment: В заголовке "удалить", в вопросе - "заменить"...

Comment: Я не знаю как это реализовать,если заменять то заменяется только один элемент.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In [32]: from itertools import groupby

In [33]: s = "aaabbbcc"

In [34]: res = ''.join(f"{a}{len(list(b))}" for a,b in groupby(list(s)))

In [35]: res
Out[35]: 'a3b3c2'
```

---

без использования модулей:

```
res = ""
cnt = 1

for i,c in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    if c != s[i+1]:
        res += f"{c}{cnt}"
        cnt = 1
    else:
        cnt += 1
    if i == len(s) - 2:
        res += f"{s[i+1]}{cnt}"
```

---

PS не вижу смысла отказываться от использования модулей (если это не учебное задание, в котором явно запрещено использовать модули).

Comment: А возможно это реализовать без сторонних модулей?

Comment: @VladilsavOl Возможно. Но зачем? `itertools` идёт из коробки, через `pip` его ставить не надо.